# How can I send List<> items as POST data the right way in Java?

Tags: java, http, post, jax-rs

I'm working on a java service where data from Table A goes to Table B. The service sends POST requests to a REST server and for each row copied, a location header gets created as a response, confirming that a new resource is created and returning a POJO as JSON when GET request is issued to the newly created resource. This is the resource method that handles POST requests.

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response migrateToMinio(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) throws Exception {
    tiedostoService = new TiedostoService();
    attachmentService = new AttachmentService();
    List<Tiedosto> tiedostoList = tiedostoService.getAllFiles();
    List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<>();
    Response r;
    Integer newRow;
    String responseData = null;
    int i=1;
    for (Tiedosto tiedosto : tiedostoList) {
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.setCustomerId(tiedosto.getCustomerId());
        attachment.setSize(tiedosto.getFileSize());
        newRow = attachmentService.createNew(attachment);
        UriBuilder builder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
        if (newRow == 1) {
            builder.path(Integer.toString(i));
            r = Response.created(builder.build()).build();
            responseData = r.getLocation().toString();
            i++;
        }
        responseList.add(responseData);
    }
    String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(responseList);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(jsonString).build();
}
```

`tiedostoService` and `attachmentService` are service classes for two tables. `tiedostoList` has all the rows from `tiedosto` table and has been iterated inside for loop so that a new row in attachments table is created for every item in `tiedostoList`. When I send POST request to `/rest/attachments`, it takes a few seconds to process and returns status 200 with a list of created resource like this:
[image: Postman output]

Now, my question is, is there a way to implement it so that the newly created resource location is returned immediately (maybe as 201 created) after it's creation, without having to wait for the final status 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a solution would presume that you the service saving the attachment (`AttachmentService`) would be able to compute the location prior to saving it. For example, the service should be able to know that if the last attachment was stored with an ID of `10`, the next attachment would be stored with an ID of `11` (or however the subsequent ID would be calculated) and therefore would have a location of `http://localhost:8080/rest/attachments/11`.

Presuming that logic is possible in your service, you could create a receipt object that contains the location of the created resource and a future that represents the saved resource. This receipt object can be returned by the service instead of the attachment itself. The implementation of such a receipt object could resemble the following:

```
public class CreationReceipt<T> {

    private final String location;
    private final Future<T> attachment;

    public CreationReceipt(String location, Future<T> attachment) {
        this.location = location;
        this.attachment = attachment;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public Future<T> getAttachment() {
        return attachment;
    }
}
```

In `AttachmentService`, there would exist a method that stores a new `Attachment` and returns a `CreationReceipt<Attachment>`:

```
public class AttachmentService {

    public CreationReceipt<Attachment> createNew(Attachment attachment) {
        String location = computeLocationFor(attachment);
        Future<Attachment> savedAttachment = saveAsynchronously(attachment);
        return new CreationReceipt<>(location, savedAttachment);
    }

    private Future<Attachment> saveAsynchronously(Attachment attachment) { ... }

    private String computeLocationFor(Attachment attachment) { ... }
}
```

The logic for pre-computing the location of an `Attachment` will depend on the specifics of your application (and I will leave it stubbed for you to add the logic), but the logic for saving an `Attachment` asynchronously can follow a common pattern. Using an `ExecutorService`, synchronous logic for saving an `Attachment` (which your application already uses) can be made asynchronous. To do this, the synchronous logic is submitted to an `ExecutorService` (using the `submit` method) and a `Future` is returned by the `ExecutorService` which wraps the saved `Attachment` and will complete when the `Attachment` is successfully saved.

An example (albeit incomplete) implementation would resemble:

```
public class AttachmentService {

    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public CreationReceipt<Attachment> createNew(Attachment attachment) {
        String location = computeLocationFor(attachment);
        Future<Attachment> savedAttachment = saveAsynchronously(attachment);
        return new CreationReceipt<>(location, savedAttachment);
    }

    private Future<Attachment> saveAsynchronously(Attachment attachment) {
        return executor.submit(() -> save(attachment));
    }

    private Attachment save(Attachment attachment) { ... }

    private String computeLocationFor(Attachment attachment) { ... }
}
```

Note that this implementation only allows one `Attachment` to be saved at a time (by nature of using `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`), but that logic can be changed by defining `executor` to use a different `ExecutorService` implementation. To complete this implementation, simply add an implementation for the `save` method that synchronously saves a new `Attachment` object (this synchronous logic should be found in your existing `createNew` method from `AttachmentService`).

From this point, the logic for saving an `Attachment` would be:

```
List<String> savedLocations = new ArrayList<>();

for (Tiedosto tiedosto : tiedostoList) {
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
    attachment.setCustomerId(tiedosto.getCustomerId());
    attachment.setSize(tiedosto.getFileSize());

    CreationReceipt<Attachment> receipt = attachmentService.createNew(attachmentToSave);
    savedLocations.add(receipt.getLocation());
}

// Do something with savedLocations
```

This is an imcomplete implementation, but it should demonstrate the basic structure that would be used. Once the loop is complete, you could include `saveLocations` as the body of the response and set the response status code to `201 Created`.